# In JavaScript, what are the frequently used parameters "info" & "tab"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, parameters

While developing a Chrome extension and reading through the documentation found at https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions, I have seen the following syntax used and have been unable to find an explanation as to what the "info" or "tab" parameters(?) are for quite some time;

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
```

"Info" and "tab" are then used like the below in various ways like they were a parent object or an interface;

```
var EncodedSelectedText = encodeURIComponent(info.selectionText).toString();
```

or

```
chrome.tabs.create({
    url: 'https://example.com/path?fragment'+EncodedSelectedText, index: tab.index + 1
});
```

They are not part of an interface, per the list of interfaces found on MDN here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API#interfaces
(Unless I am missing something?)

This ***must*** have a simple explanation that I have been unable to find. Please, if someone could provide a link to the documentation about this on MDN or some other authoritative resource, it would be so very helpful.

Comment: These are objects and their contents is described in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus/#event-onClicked) for *this* particular API for extensions, which is not a web API. The links that describe the parameter types are clickable.

Comment: @wOxxOm Would you care to add that as an answer to this question? That was exactly what I was looking for and would accept it as an answer if you would kindly add it as such.

Comment: @wOxxOm - I have found more related information and am having more difficulty understanding this additional part. In the [chrome-extensions-samples/api/contextMenus/global_context_search/background.js](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/blob/main/api/contextMenus/global_context_search/background.js) file, there is the following on line 26 — `item.selectionText`. I cannot find any reference to an 'item' object in the documentation like I could for the 'info' object. What am I missing?

Comment: In JavaScript the name of a function parameter can be anything you want e.g. `item`. Simply see the documentation for a parameter at position 1 i.e. in this case it's `info` and its type is described in the linked `OnClickData`.